# How to access a thread's object from another thread - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a specific class which extends Thread. In my main i create a number of threads of that class. Each thread creates an object of class Hero (a class created by me).

Is there a way that one thread can access the object of the class Hero of another thread? 
I want to have a way to compare two objects of class Hero of two different threads, either having a method tha can have as arguments the two objects of the two different threads OR by having a way to pass values of the object of one thread to another thread.

Comment: Smells like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605476/java-help-needed-sharing-an-object-between-two-threads-and-main-program. In the future, please make use of the search bar before asking questions. Of course, we'd be happy to answer any questions not answered by the above mentioned thread here.

Comment: An object does not belong to a thread. A Java application plays with object references. Just pass them around where they are required and can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have it so that the Class that extends Thread accepts an object of Class Hero in its constructor, like so:

```
public class YourClass extends Thread{
     private Hero hero;

     YourClass(Hero hero){
          this.hero= hero;           
         }
 }
```

This way you can create the object first and add it to an ArrayList, before passing the reference to the constructor of the new thread object:

```
ArrayList heroes= new ArrayList<Hero>();//this should be declared at the class level
Hero hero= new Hero();
heroes.add(hero);
YourClass thread= new YourClass(hero);
```

The ArrayList of Hero objects is now available to all your threads, and you can write a method which iterates through it to find the object you are looking for. How you do this is largely down to what it is exactly you want to do.

Comment: Sharing an ArrayList can be dangerous if you're not handling synchronization correctly. I would rephrase your answer either using a synchronized block or something from the concurrent package.

Answer (score 0):

So... as others have said you can just put all your Hero objects in a static list, dictionary or other structure that everyone can access.

BUT its sounds to me like what you are trying to do actually is create Active Objects http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_object

When you have Active objects, each Active Object has its own thread that is tightly wound around its own processing loop.  That loop is fed by a queue of "messages" that come in from other objects.

SO each object stores a reference to other objects it wants to talk to, **not** a reference to the threads.  The threads are hidden inside the object.  Each object only exposes one method to other objects -- "QueueMessage", which puts messages for processing on that queue.

That queue must be implemented as a thread-safe data structure. The easiest way to do that in Java is with a ConcurrentLinkedQueue

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html